# HighCharts : Highlight entire series when hover and restore state when out

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I try to highlight an entire serie when hovering in a column chart. Due to the nature of the needed chart all columns are set side by side without spacing.

I partially succeeded in doing so by using **mouseOver** and **mouseOut** on the series, but it doesn't work when hovering to the next element of the same serie. The entire serie should remain highlighted, but i'm not able to disable the mouseOut if hovered within the same serie.

I tried doing by this code:

```
        series: [
            {
                events: {
                mouseOver: function() {
                    for(var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++)
                    {
                        this.data[i].setState('hover');
                    }

                },
                mouseOut: function(){

                    for(var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++)
                    {
                        this.data[i].setState('');
                    }
                }},
```

I put this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhjbY/)

When you hover the lightblue serie, it get highlighted entirely, but when hovering to the next element within that serie, the serie should remain highlighted entirely, but my expirement the elements get highlighted at random.

[image]

Any help appreciated

---

**Update:**

Based on the **solution provided by [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987838/robert-rozas)** I added a little modification. By introducing the activation of the hover state on the tooltip formatter event, the mouseOver behavior became redundant and I removed it.

Solution : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9W8h4/3/)

Comment: Steven, check my answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a little change:

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
                    {
                        this.series.data[i].setState('hover');
                    }


                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/9W8h4/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add events to each series please see here

or here : http://jsfiddle.net/uST2P/

```
$(function () {

    var myCustomEvent = {
        mouseOver: function () {
            overSeriesIndex = this.index;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {

                this.data[i].setState('hover');
            }

        },
        mouseOut: function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                this.data[i].setState('');
            }
        }
    };

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            width: 585
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0,
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 1,
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                pointWidth: 100
            }
        },
        series: [{
            events: myCustomEvent,
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {

            events: myCustomEvent,
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            events: myCustomEvent,
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sylwester, but I was aware of the fact that I needed to apply them to all series. The problem was that the highlighted state wasn't maintained when moving from one block of a series to the next, which your solution does not fix.

Comment: @Steven Have you found out any solution for this? I have seen some options to use series ID.

Comment: @Jyothu In fact I did, as mentioned in the edit of the question. Here's a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/9W8h4/3/